# Split pandas dataframe into multiple dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, split

I have a dataframe where several of the columns represent categorical data. I would like to split it up based on each combination. Below is a simplified version of what I have:

```
In [394]: df.head(10)
Out[394]: 
         existing  priority  State payment
0               Y         N     FL    10.4
1               N         N     CA   918.0
2               Y         N     CA   493.0
3               Y         N     FL   743.2
4               Y         Y     CA   898.0
5               N         N     CA  -237.0
6               Y         Y     CA   510.0
7               N         N     CA  -480.0
8               Y         N     FL  -125.0
9               Y         Y     CA   211.0
```

I would like to have one dataframe that contains all entries of one combination of the first three variables, i.e.:

```
         existing  priority  State payment
0               Y         N     FL    10.4
1               Y         N     FL   743.2
2               Y         N     FL  -125.0
```

...and each combination thereafter...

```
         existing  priority  State payment
0               N         N     CA   918.0
1               N         N     CA  -237.0
2               N         N     CA  -480.0
```

...etc. Is there any way to do this? Could the naming convention be automated so it contains the names of each variable combination?

Let me know if there's any ambiguity in what I'm asking here, and thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Do you need to split the dfs? you can just groupby on those cols and then after get the groups `gp = df.groupby(['existing', 'priority', 'State']) groups = gp.groups` you can then get each group using `gp.get_group(group_name)`

Comment: I need them split. The intent is to order them after they're split, then perform operations based on their order. The split prevents an operation between two rows that aren't in the same group, i.e. a "Y,N,FL" row being subtracted from a "N,N,CA" row.

Answer (score 0):

@EdChum is correct.  It's difficult to think up what you are imagining is appropriately split.

---

***@EdChum 's answer***

```
cols = ['existing', 'priority', 'State']
grps = df.groupby(cols)
gnms = grps.groups.keys()
grpd = grps.apply(pd.DataFrame.reset_index, drop=True)

for name in gnms:
    print('\n{}\n\n{}\n'.format(name, grpd.loc[name]))

('Y', 'N', 'FL')

  existing priority State  payment
0        Y        N    FL     10.4
1        Y        N    FL    743.2
2        Y        N    FL   -125.0


('Y', 'Y', 'CA')

  existing priority State  payment
0        Y        Y    CA    898.0
1        Y        Y    CA    510.0
2        Y        Y    CA    211.0


('Y', 'N', 'CA')

  existing priority State  payment
0        Y        N    CA    493.0


('N', 'N', 'CA')

  existing priority State  payment
0        N        N    CA    918.0
1        N        N    CA   -237.0
2        N        N    CA   -480.0
```

Comment: Thank you very much @piRSquared . Still new to this and what is in my head is often far from what is correct coding. Much appreciated!